# Jquery DataTables Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, datatables

JQuery noob here ...

I have a Question regarding the DataTables Plugin.[DataTables link.](http://www.datatables.net/)

The Plugin claims that:

> A common use case for this is when you
>   are displaying live information which
>   could be periodically updated

Being a newbie, I cannot figure out how to initialize the Table using Ajax, so that the table updates itself dynamically if the server information is changed. ( That is when new information is added in the server, the change is displayed on the table real time)

P.S: I am using PHP as the server side script.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot happen automatically .. you will have to poll the server for changes .. either you or the plugin ..

You could utilize the [`fnReloadAjax`](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) method.. but you will have to manually (or though a time interval) call it ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fnUpdate` or `fnAddData` functions and pass the information as an array, line by line.

```
var dataTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
$.post('myServer.php', {update: 'table'}, function(data){
    var newTRNum = dataTable.getNodes().length + 1;
    $.each(data, function(i, tableRowInfo){
        dataTable.fnUpdate(tablerowInfo, newTrNum, 0);
        newTrNum++;
    });
}, 'json');
```

I haven't tested it, but likely something to that effect.